# JQuery: Capture Enter + Done/Return on iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone, keypress

I've got a page w/ a Search field that's meant to work by typing your search term and then hitting enter. This works fine on desktop browsers, but my code that captures the "Enter" button press doesn't work on iPhone (and possibly other mobile browsers).

HTML is a simple input field (which is not inside a FORM element):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 action-row padding pull-right xs-margin-up">
    <span class="k-textbox k-button k-space-left col-xs-12 search-box">
        <i class="fa-icon-search"></i>
        <input id="search" placeholder="Search" />
    </span>
</div>
```

And then I'm binding the keypress in the document.ready:

```
$(this).keypress(function(event) {
    if ($('#search').is(":focus") && event.which == 13) {   
        search = $('#search').val();    

        generateView();
    }
});

/*$('#search').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {    
        search = $('#search').val();    

        generateView();
    }
});*/
```

You'll notice the two different versions - the first one is the only one that works for me at all, no matter what the browser. I tried the second one based on some other Stack Overflow threads, but it doesn't even work on Firefox, nevermind the iPhone.

I created this fiddle, which doesn't do anything on the iphone: http://jsfiddle.net/tb653201/

Comment: When I accessed your fiddle on my iPhone 6 using Safari, I saw an alert raised. Can you please try accessing this fiddle on your iPhone again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to get around the issues you're having is to wrap your input in a form tag, add a hidden submit button, and then use jQuery's "submit" events to trigger them.  Mobile picks up the fact that it's a form and handles the "enter" key press differently than it does in regular typing.

```js
$("#myform").on("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // Your custom search functions here
});
```

```css
#myform input[type='submit'] { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 action-row padding pull-right xs-margin-up">
  <span class="k-textbox k-button k-space-left col-xs-12 search-box">
    <i class="fa-icon-search"></i>
    <form id="myform" action="#">
      <input id="search" placeholder="Search" />
      <input type="submit" value="">
    </form>
  </span>
</div>
```

See this for more info:  https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: I hope more js devs would structure their front end architecture this way. This leverages the default behavior of browsers, no need for you to repeat a browser behavior with js when you stick to standards. kudos!

Comment: Thanks Tammy, it's looking like I will need to add a form, which I was hoping to avoid, since we're actually going to need a main form on this page at some point in the future.

Comment: @shimmoril  No problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You could test for the return key result in the value but it needs to be in a textarea to catch it

also it's a "framework free" solution but can be used with jQuery as well

```js
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup', checkValue);

function checkValue(event){
  var input = event.target;
  var splitedText = input.value.split(/\n/g);
  input.value = splitedText[0];
  if(splitedText.length> 1)
    alert('enter or whatever was pressed');
}
```

```css
textarea.input{
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <body>
  
    <textarea id="search" class="input" placeholder="search" cols="30" rows="1" wrap="off"></textarea>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh!, and if you want to be able to past a paragraph with multiple lines you may change `input.value = splitedText[0];` for `input.value = splitedText.join(' ');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#search').keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {   
        search = $('#search').val();    

        generateView();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I believe you should do is if you have a search input, is to give it a ['search'](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.search.html) type. Then you also leverage other features of the search input type such as datalists.

Comment: The problem with this, though, is that it's still in early adoption by browsers.  As http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp shows, it's not widely compatible yet.

Comment: Yes, but it always falls back to a text input box (graceful degradation and all that) - and you can use JS libraries such as Modernizr to provide the missing functonality....